# RMS Normalize ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, normalize

I’m new to ffmpeg and would like to create a script that can RMS normalize audio files to a specified RMS (mean) dB level. Can someone show how to do this?

I’ve used dynaudnorm, but can’t get the desired output, I believe it’s due it using frames opposed to analyzing the full file.

To RMS normalize, my thought is to use a conditional statement to create a filter that can automatically read RMS (mean) level of an audio file and then automatically set the RMS (mean) level to a specified dB level.

Theoretical example:

```
ffmpeg -i (inputfilename) -af "normalize_rms=-20dB" (outputfilename)
```

Explanation of Conditional Statement and Example:

- Pass 1: run astats or volumedetect to calculate RMS level.
- Pass 2: If RMS level = X dB, then add Y dB level to match the user specified dB level.
  Example:   If RMS level = -30dB, and user specified RMS level = -20dB, then add 10dB.

Comment: steve have you got your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `bash` script, that parses audiofile volume and then normalizes it according to its volume. The main idea is taken from answer to a similar [SO question](https://superuser.com/questions/323119/how-can-i-normalize-audio-using-ffmpeg), where also other approaches are  discussed.

```
sound_info="$(ffmpeg -i sound.mp3 -af volumedetect -f null -y nul $1 2>&1)"
max_volume_line="$(echo "$sound_info" | grep 'max_volume')"
max_volume_line="$(echo "$max_volume_line" | grep -Po "max_volume:\s+\S+\s+dB")"
volume="$(echo "$max_volume_line" | grep -Po "[-|+]?\d+\.?\d*")"
ffmpeg -i sound.mp3 -af "volume=$volume" normalized_sound.mp3
```

If you would like just normalize the perceived loudness, `ffmpeg` documentation [suggests to use](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioVolume) the `​loudnorm` filter.

Comment: The four identical sed lines: you've got an original.txt and an original1.tmp but not an original.tmp ? What are those four lines trying to do?

Comment: @Rup, sorry, I've had to debug the script myself before posting. Now I took the main idea and rewrote script myself, now it do not use files to save temporary variables

Comment: Note that grep on macos doesn't have -P, but -E should work here across systems.